# Should explicit keyword be used for move constructors?

Tags: c++

This code does not compile. But if I remove the `explicit` keyword from the move constructor then it works. Why?

```
struct Bar {
    Bar() {}
    explicit Bar(const Bar& x) {}
    explicit Bar(Bar&& x) {}
};

Bar bar() {
    Bar x;
    return x;
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Bar::Bar(Bar&)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return statement copy-initializes the return value from the operand.

Copy-initialization doesn't consider `explicit` constructors. But `explicit` doesn't change that the constructors you defined are copy and move constructors. Therefore no other implicit constructors will be declared.

In effect, there is no viable constructor left to construct the return value.

If you remove the `explicit` on either of the constructors, there will be a viable constructor to construct the return value and it will compile. The move constructor will be preferred if it is not `explicit`, because of the special semantics of return statements.

---

Copy and move constructors should usually *not* be `explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

`return x;` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which won't consider `explicit` constructors.

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.

BTW for the [`return` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) like `return x;`, the move constructor of `Bar` will be considered firstly; then the copy constructor if the move constructor is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no. Do you want move-construction to be explicit? If so, yes. Otherwise: no. But typically only converting constructors are `explicit`. (I occasionally make the copy-c'tor `explicit`, delete the copy-assignment operator, but leave the move-c'tor implicit when I have a "heavy" class that almost never want to deeply-copy, so users can say `Foo(foo)` if they want a copy, but they have to think about it.)